# How can Seq[+A] be covariant in A?

Tags: scala, covariance

How can Seq[+A] be covariant in A if A occurs in contravariant position:

```
def :+ (elem: A) : Seq[A] ?
```

As I understand, a method argument type is a contravariant position. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the *use case* signature. It is not a real signature, just what you'll usually see in the common use case.

The real signature is:

```
def :+ [B >: A, That] ( elem : B )(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], B, That] ) : That
```

Which, as you see, doesn't even guarantee a `Seq` return, much less `A`.

Comment: To build on what Daniel said, the collection methods return _a new collection_ and these can have widened type.  So, yes, a `Seq[A]` can only contains `A`s, but your new `Seq` could have its type widened so that it can contain more than just `A`.

Comment: It's a bit of a shame that the use case signature uses `:+(elem: A): Seq[A]` instead of `:+[B >: A](elem: B): Seq[B]` though.

Comment: @Kris I concur: `:+[B >: A](elem: B): Seq[B]` is much more intuitive. Can we ask the Scala guys to change the API docs ?

Comment: @Misha Sure. Go to the Scala issue tracker and development wiki (http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala), and open an enhancement ticket. I'm not sure if the proper classification would be library or scaladoc, though.